# How to make video FASTAPI Streaming, not returning a whole file?

Tags: boto3, fastapi

Please tell me why, when the video is displayed for the first time through the api below, I get in DevTools that I upload all the videos at once (the size of the uploaded object is equal to the size of the video in S3 storage) although I made a Streaming Response, is it possible to somehow make the first frame loaded as the first 5 megabytes?

```
from private.boto3_client import boto3_client 
from fastapi import HTTPException, Response
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse 
import io 
 
 
def get_video(video_token, range):
    response = boto3_client.get_object(Bucket='******', Key=f'{video_token}.mp4')
    
    def generate():
        for chunk in response['Body'].iter_chunks():
            yield chunk

    return StreamingResponse(content=generate(), media_type='video/mp4')`
```

I tried to set the get_object Range argument, but nothing worked